# Can't run a MapReduce job on hadoop 2.4.0

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am new to hadoop and here is my problem. I have configured hadoop 2.4.0 with jdk1.7.60 on cluster of 3 machine. I am able to execute all the commands of hadoop. Now I have modified wordcount example and created jar file. I have already executed with this jar file on hadoop 1.2.1 and got the result. But now on hadoop 2.4.0 I am not getting any result.

Command used for execution

```
$hadoop jar WordCount.jar WordCount /data/webdocs.dat /output
```

I am getting following message from the setup:

```
14/06/29 19:35:18 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /192.168.2.140:8040
14/06/29 19:35:18 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
14/06/29 19:35:19 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/06/29 19:35:19 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:12
14/06/29 19:35:19 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1403905542893_0004
14/06/29 19:35:19 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1403905542893_0004
14/06/29 19:35:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://192.168.2.140:8088/proxy/application_1403905542893_0004/
14/06/29 19:35:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1403905542893_0004
```

At this point no message change. I waited for 15 to 20 minutes but still the same.

This is what I see on resource manager's web page regarding the job:

```
State - ACCEPTED
FinalStatus - UNDEFINED
Progress - (progress bar in 0%)
Tracking UI - UNASSIGNED

Apps Submitted - 1
Apps Pending - 1
Apps Running - 0
```

I tried the other yarn command for execution but got the same result

```
$yarn jar WordCount.jar WordCount /data/webdocs.dat /output
```

Here is the output of jps:

```
21485 NameNode
23142 DataNode
28504 Jps
21704 ResourceManager
22082 JobHistoryServer
```

Any help or guidance will be highly appriciated.

Comment: You'll need to look in the RM logs to see if there's something odd there. It has accepted your app but it isn't running yet. Maybe you're requesting more resources that your RM has available.

Comment: Hey apart from being new to Hadoop, I am new to Java as well. Please can you tell m how can I create Word Count jar?

Comment: @nish compile your filename.java using command **javac filename.java**   now use this command to create jar file **jar cvf filename.jar .*.class**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was the mistake in the configuration file of the hadoop.
There was bind exception on the port 8040 for resourcemanager.

I changed the hadoop yarn-site.xml from (old yarn-site.xml):

```
<configuration>
<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
  <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
  <value>192.168.2.140:8025</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
  <value>192.168.2.140:8030</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
  <value>192.168.2.140:8040</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

To (new yarn-site.xml):

```
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
  <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

I deleted the other line in hadoop configuration
Then I gace following commands to start resourcemanager and nodemanager

```
$yarn-daemon.sh start nodemanager
$yarn-daemon.sh start resourcemanager
```

Then I tried executing my job and it was successfull.