# YarnApplicationState: ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register

Tags: linux, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-computing, hadoop-yarn

I am new to Hadoop ecosystem.

I recently tried Hadoop (2.7.1) on a single-node Cluster without any problems and decided to move on to a Multi-node cluster having 1 namenode and 2 datanodes.

However I am facing a weird issue. **Whatever Jobs that I try to run, are stuck with the following message:**

on the web interface:

```
YarnApplicationState: ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register
```

and in the cli:

```
16/01/05 17:52:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1451083949804_0001
```

They don't even start and at this point I am not sure what changes I need to make in order to make it work.

**Here's what I have tried to resolve:**

1. disabling firewall on all nodes
2. setting lower resource limits
3. configuring under different machines, routers and distros

I would really appreciate any help (even a minute hint) in correct direction.

**I have followed these instructions (configuration):**

- [Running Hadoop on Ubuntu Linux (Multi-Node Cluster)](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/)
- [How To Setup Multi Node Hadoop 2 (YARN) Cluster](http://arturmkrtchyan.com/how-to-setup-multi-node-hadoop-2-yarn-cluster)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally got this solved. Posting detailed steps for future reference. (only for test environment)

**Hadoop (2.7.1) Multi-Node cluster configuration**

1. Make sure that you have a reliable network without host isolation. Static IP assignment is preferable or at-least have extremely long DHCP lease. Additionally all nodes (Namenode/master & Datanodes/slaves) should have a common user account with same password; in case you don't, make such user account on all nodes. Having same username and password on all nodes makes things a bit less complicated.
2. *[on all machines]* First configure all nodes for single-node cluster. You can use my script that I have posted over [here](https://github.com/user501254/BD_STTP_2016/blob/master/InstallHadoop.sh).
3. execute these commands in a new terminal

   *[on all machines]* ↴

   ```
   stop-dfs.sh;stop-yarn.sh;jps
   rm -rf /tmp/hadoop-$USER
   ```

   *[on Namenode/master only]* ↴

   ```
   rm -rf ~/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode
   ```

   *[on Datanodes/slaves only]* ↴

   ```
   rm -rf ~/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode
   ```
4. *[on all machines]* Add IP addresses and corresponding Host names for all nodes in the cluster.

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/hosts
   ```

   hosts

   ```
   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx master
   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxy slave1
   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxz slave2
   # Additionally you may need to remove lines like "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx localhost", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxy localhost", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxz localhost" etc if they exist.
   # However it's okay keep lines like "127.0.0.1 localhost" and others.
   ```
5. *[on all machines]* Configure iptables

   Allow default or custom ports that you plan to use for various Hadoop daemons through the firewall

   OR

   much easier, disable iptables

   - on RedHat like distros (Fedora, CentOS)

     ```
     sudo systemctl disable firewalld
     sudo systemctl stop firewalld
     ```
   - on Debian like distros (Ubuntu)

     ```
     sudo ufw disable
     ```
6. *[on Namenode/master only]* Gain ssh access from Namenode (master) to all Datnodes (slaves).

   ```
   ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $USER@slave1
   ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $USER@slave2
   ```

   confirm things by running `ping slave1`, `ssh slave1`, `ping slave2`, `ssh slave2` etc. You should have a proper response. (Remember to exit each of your ssh sessions by typing `exit` or closing the terminal. To be on the safer side I also made sure that all nodes were able to access each other and not just the Namenode/master.)
7. *[on all machines]* edit core-site.xml file

   ```
   nano /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml
   ```

   core-site.xml

   ```
   <configuration>
       <property>
           <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
           <value>master:9000</value>
           <description>NameNode URI</description>
       </property>
   </configuration>
   ```
8. *[on all machines]* edit yarn-site.xml file

   ```
   nano /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml
   ```

   yarn-site.xml

   ```
   <configuration>
       <property>
           <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
           <value>master</value>
           <description>The hostname of the RM.</description>
       </property>
       <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
            <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
       </property>
       <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
            <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
       </property>
   </configuration>
   ```
9. *[on all machines]* modify slaves file, remove the text "localhost" and add slave hostnames

   ```
   nano /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/slaves
   ```

   slaves

   ```
   slave1
   slave2
   ```

   (I guess having this only on Namenode/master will also work but I did this on all machines anyway. Also note that in this configuration master behaves only as resource manger, this is how I intent it to be.)
10. *[on all machines]* modify hdfs-site.xml file to change the value for property `dfs.replication` to something > 1 (at-least to the number of slaves in the cluster; here I have two slaves so I would set it to 2)
11. *[on Namenode/master only]* (re)format the HDFS through namenode

    ```
    hdfs namenode -format
    ```
12. *[optional]*

    - remove `dfs.datanode.data.dir` property from master's hdfs-site.xml file.
    - remove `dfs.namenode.name.dir` property from all slave's hdfs-site.xml file.

**TESTING (execute only on Namenode/master)**

```
start-dfs.sh;start-yarn.sh

echo "hello world hello Hello" > ~/Downloads/test.txt

hadoop fs -mkdir /input

hadoop fs -put ~/Downloads/test.txt /input

hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-*.jar wordcount /input /output
```

wait for a few seconds and the mapper and reducer should begin.

---

These links helped me with the issue:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24544207/2534513
- [Hadoop YARN Installation: The definitive guide#Cluster Installation](http://www.alexjf.net/blog/distributed-systems/hadoop-yarn-installation-definitive-guide/#cluster-installation)

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when I ran

"hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.4.jar wordcount /calculateCount/ /output"

this command stopped there,

I tracked the job, and find "there are 15 missing blocks, and they are all corrupted"

then I did the following:
1) ran "hdfs fsck / "
2) ran "hdfs fsck / -delete "
3) added "-A INPUT -p tcp -j ACCEPT" to /etc/sysconfig/iptables on the two datanodes
4) ran "stop-all.sh and start-all.sh"

everything goes well

I think the firewall is the key point.